# Mouse and Keyboard will not work Windows 7 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, keyboard, mouse, logitech

My mouse and keyboard work fine in Ubuntu, as well as grub. However, when I boot into Windows 7, I cannot get past the login screen because the mouse and keyboard do not work. The lack of light on my mouse indicates that it's not even on. This happened before when I tried to manually install Ubuntu (partitioning myself with gparted) so I reinstalled and let Ubuntu do everything for me ("Install alongside Windows 7" option) and I thought that fixed the problem because the mouse and keyboard worked twice in a row. Now, however, they have stopped working again. I am using a Logitech K120 keyboard and a Deathadder mouse. Both are plugged into usb 2.0 ports.

Comment: I've experienced something similar, and with hard shut down and then reboot into Windows 7, it operated again, but the solution is not nice.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

when you boot from win 7 try to plug out both mouse and keyboard & plug them again at same port. If it doesn’t solve your problem then try different port.

Answer (score 0):

For me, trying this has solved the pb

I got it fixed. The problem was related to USB 3.0.

Solution was to change Intel xHCI Mode from "Smart Auto" to "Auto" (or just disable it) under Advanced - USB Configuration. So it will not use USB 3.0 during the boot.

Note: Also make sure that Legacy USB support it set to Auto or Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest please check your bios setting and make sure the USB legacy is On/Enabled or Auto mode. Hopefully, it will work or rather pls reset your Bios setting and try once on default bootable settings and just make sure USB legacy is on and different motherboard holds different settings check for other USB Settings under configuration tab/menu.
Check if any other USB device is connected to your device or not pls unplug them and boot.

xHCI enables various versions of USB to work with USB 2.0 Host. so disable it and use ur keyboard and mouse which I guess would be of 2.0 and would work fine when disabled.